# GraalVM: Polyglot applications: Java classes in C++ IDE (including documentation, debug support etc.)

Tags: java, c++, ide, code-generation, graalvm

I'm evaluating if [polyglot applications using GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/polyglot-programming/) could be a solution for our next project. The goal would be to reuse the existing Java data model in C++ at 'develop time' (C++ IDE). Ideally with documentation (Javadoc), code completion and the ability to debug into the Java classes. So the key question is: Is it possible to work seamlessly with a Java data model in C++ IDE using GraalVM? Or (if not) what is the least painful way to do so?

After searching around I now get the feeling that this won't work without generating a C/C++ representation of the Java classes. If this is the right place to look at (feel free to point me to better/correct resources) and I'm getting it right [Build a Native Shared Library](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/guides/build-native-shared-library/) and [Java Native Interface (JNI) in Native Image](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/dynamic-features/JNI/) seems to suggest code generation of some sort is inevitable.

To elaborate more on this:

1. I hoped that GraalVM would provide something to also remove the language barrier at development time (Developing source code in the IDE), but this seems not to be the case, right?
2. I hoped that there wouldn't be the need to generate additional code at all, but the only help I can get from GraalVM would be calling something like `native-image -jar <jarfile> --shared` for getting C header files (so yes, code generation, but at least I don't have to implement one by myself).
3. It's clear to me, that the C++ IDE needs to know somehow how the data model looks like (classes and their structure). I hoped that GraalVM would perhaps introduce a new mechanism implemented in IDEs to access libraries in other languages. Instead of including classic header files the workflow would be to load a Java JAR into a 'GraalVM instance' managed by the C++ IDE and the C++ IDE communicates with this 'GraalVM instance' and retrieves the header data from there, e.g. So you would put  something like "#include graal://com.example.fancyLibrary:1.0" into your C++ code instead of using 'normal' header files.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what GraalVM does.

Comment: Yes and no. I understand your comment: GraalVM is a VM for Java in the first place. But on the other hand to make polyglot application development easier I would expect some infrastructure around it. So yes, perhaps this is way out of the scope of GraalVM -- but then: Are there any other projects in the GraalVM sphere trying to make an integration as seamless as possible?

Comment: GraalVM is an execution time engine. It does nothing for development time or IDEs.